# Finding another attempt to solve problems about binary string

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary

I've solved this problem about binary string for a long time ago:

> How many binary string having length N that doesn't contain any consecutive bit 1 in it? Print all situations can be exist. Print in any order you want".
>
> For example: With N=3, we have:
>
> 100
>
> 101
>
> 010
>
> 001
>
> 000

I used generation-method to solve it, and it's time complexity is O(2^N) or O(N*2^N) - as we've known.

Yesterday, my friend asked me about that problem, I told him that way to solve it, and I also though about another ways to solve it by decreasing time complexity - it may be O(n^2) or some else.

Does anyone can solve it with time complexity less than O(2^N)?

Thanks.

Comment: You left out `000`. The number of strings of length N is Fib(N+1), and you can compute Fib(x) with O(log(x)) operations.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: I've also known that way to count the number of strings, but I don't know the way to print it all :(

Comment: @rici the same above

Comment: If you want to generate and print each number, the complexity is going to be exponential O(k^N), just to generate and print each one! (K may be a little less than 2 because Fib(N) grows slower than 2^N - it is approximately (1 + sqrt(5))/2 or 1.61).

Comment: You can use a recursive method. Generate the strings of length `N-1` that match the criteria, then prepend `0` to each, and `1` to each one that doesn't begin with `1`.

Comment: @Anders Can you explain more about your algorithm with that complexity ?

Comment: @Barmar your algorithm also has the time complexity approximate to O(2^n) ?

Comment: @LeDuongTuanAnh That's better than generate-and-test, which is O(n*2^n) -- it has to generatee 2^n values, and each test is O(n).

Comment: You know the number of strings with length N is Fibinacci(N) or Fib(N). Assume it takes O(1) to generate or even just print each string. It would then take O(Fib(N)) just to do that. Fib(N) has a closed form solution that is roughly N^1.61, so the **lower bound** to print all the strings is O(N^1.61). I believe that the algorithm suggested by @Barmar is both the skeleton of a proof of why the number of strings is Fib(N) and would run in O(1) per-instance so then O(N^1.61) total because it requires simple enumeration of all the values.

Comment: @Anders Why isn't the number of strings with length N = a^N, where a is the number of letters on the alphabet?

Comment: @Barmar if you work it out for N = 2 and then N = 3 , maybe 4 you can see that, for example for N=3 you can prepend '0' to all 3 numbers {00, 01, 10} of N=2, but can only prepend '1' to 2 of them, not all 3. But instead of prepending 1, look at it as prepending '10' to the 2 of length N=1 { 0, 1 }. So for f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2). Therefore the number of _valid_ strings of length N is Fib(n), which, as expected, is less than 2^N because all are not valid, but is still exponential.

Comment: @Anders I didn't think you were talking about the valid strings, since in a generate-and-test method you have to generate all strings.

Comment: @Barmar - OK, yes. I didn't notice you were testing each. You don't need to do that. Funny, because the way you stated the problem made the solution crystal clear to me, even though I already knew if was Fib(n), it made it make more sense. See my silly answer.

Comment: @Barmar can you write for me your pseudo code?... I still don't understand yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python. No maths, just strings.

```
import sys
def nodup(n, prefix=""):
  if n == 0:
    print(prefix)
  elif n == 1:
    print(prefix+"0")
    print(prefix+"1")
  else:
    nodup(n-1, prefix+"0")
    nodup(n-2, prefix+"10")

nodup(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: You can see the number of string concatenations, prints, etc. is linear to Fib(n). So O(Fib(N)) or O(1.61^N), *not* Fib(N)*N. Just to check, `time python t1.py 32 >/dev/null` gives me 1.68s, and N=37 gives me 18.09s. Very close to a ratio of 1.61^5.

Comment: O(Fib(N)) is O(1.61^N * N) is O(1.61 ^ (N+log N)), so even if there was a linear difference (perhaps due to having to print more characters for bigger N?), it's by far hidden by the exponential term. Big O is just an approximation anyhow - time to concatenate strings is not constant, CPU cache effects, etc. So there is always some variation on what the operations we're counting are and if they are truly constant. I don't think anyone counts that fact that multiplies and divides can be slower or faster depending on the data, for example. It's definitely less than 2^n - try doing that for N=32.

Comment: Thanks so much :D I got it